# Cancel AWS CDK deployment after X failed task

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

I am deploying a service on aws using an ApplicationLoadBalancedEc2Service.

Sometimes while doing some testing, I deploy a configuration that results in errors. The problem is that instead of canceling the deployment, the cdk just hangs for hours. The reason is that AWS tries to keep spinning up a task (which fails due to my wrong configuration).

Right now I have to set the task number to 0 through the AWS console. This will cause to successfully complete the deployment and allow me to spin a new version.

Is there a way to cancel the deployment and just rollback after X amount of failed tasks?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for the [Circuit Breaker](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedEc2Service.html#circuitbreaker) feature:

```
declare const cluster: ecs.Cluster;
const loadBalancedEcsService = new ecsPatterns.ApplicationLoadBalancedEc2Service(this, 'Service', {
  cluster,
  memoryLimitMiB: 1024,
  taskImageOptions: {
    image: ecs.ContainerImage.fromRegistry('test'),
  },
  desiredCount: 2,
  circuitBreaker: { rollback: true }
});
```

It will give your deploy between 10 and 200 tries (0.5 times your desired task count, with these min/max values), before to cancel your deploy. The `rollback` argument allows you to re-launch tasks with the previous task definition.

Comment: tried that option, doesnt seem to work. 1 replica wanted, 11 failed deployments and still attempting. Also it would be nice to be able to define the amount of tries instead of getting that value from desired task count. Maybe 1 failed try is enough for me to want a rollback.

Comment: Circuit Breaker is only available for rolling updates deployment types (`deployment_controller`), can you check that you're using it? I'm using this features on dozens of various services and can confirm it is working as expected.

Comment: It worked for me. I'm deploying `FargateService` using CDK and have `desired_count=1`. After 10 tasks failed to be deployed, after some time this CDK stack  rolled back.

Answer (score 0):

One way is to configure [CodeDeploy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/en_us/codedeploy/latest/userguide/deployment-steps-ecs.html) to roll back the service to its previous version if the new deployment fails.  This won't "cancel the CDK deployment", but will stabilize the service.

Another way is to add a [Custom Resource](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib-readme.html#custom-resources) with an [asynchronous provider](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.custom_resources-readme.html#asynchronous-providers-iscomplete) to poll the ECS service status, signaling CloudFormation if your success condition is not met.  This *will* revert the CDK deployment itself.